# Getting a 'WS trust response'-error when executing Connect-PnPOnline in Powershell

Tags: powershell, adfs

Since I updated the Powershell Pnp-module to the latest version (1.10.0) I get the following error when trying to connect to PnpOnline:

PS C:\Users\Admin> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://testscholengroepbrussel.sharepoint.com/sites/so-kae"
Connect-PnPOnline : There was an error parsing WS-Trust response from the endpoint. This may occur if there is an issue with your ADFS configuration. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa-troubleshooting for more details. Error Message: Federated service at https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/testscholengroepbrussel.onmicrosoft.com/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-r
equest-id=65f9e4ff-ffc5-4286-8c97-d58fd2323ab1 returned error: Authentication Failure
At line:1 char:1

- Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://testscholengroepbrussel.sharepoint.co ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], MsalClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException,PnP.PowerShell.Co 
  mmands.Base.ConnectOnline
  ```

There is no ADFS configured on the tenant, nor any other SSO-configuration made. I do not have the problem on another tenant ...

There's almost no info available on this problem, can anyone help?

Thx,
David